# How to open mysite in China

Tags: networking, proxy, server, mirror, great-firewall-of-china

We have deployed a site in US, and it is working fine. But i'm unable to open my site in china because of great firewall of china

How we can access the site in China

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to create sub-website for another country is matching the stylistic and literary attributes of local. So that the website will work well without interruption.

Another way is to buildup a forward proxy server in the region that country can accessed. Then the proxy server redirect all the requests to you site. But this way is easy caught, and then the proxy server will be blocked by the Country Firewall. Here you may setup an encrypted tunnel between the proxy server and your site.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-14-04-droplet

http://blog.boyeau.com/cheat-sheet-establishing-a-vpn-tunnel-between-2-linux-servers/

https://vexxhost.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-setup-your-own-vpn-with-pptp-on-linux-centos-ubuntu-debian/

Comment: can you please explain more in detail, i don't understand what to do?
Do we need to setup a proxy server in US or China?
Thanks

Comment: It may be anywhere  that has not been blocked by the country firewall.

Comment: We deployed our site in US, we need to access it in china also, so can you please tell me where we need place proxy server

Do we need any other servers in China other than proxy

Comment: As I explained in the second way, no other server is needed apart form the proxy server.  But you should have a domain name bound to that server to avoid use ip to access that server.

Comment: hi @KrisRoofe i'm checking that how can i setup proxy server, i'll update you with the results, if you can show me some guide to setup this it will be more helpful, Thanks

Comment: @rak I've edit my answer, add some useful links, hope it helps.

Comment: thanks i will update with results

Comment: i'm still stuck with proxy setup, after setup completed i'll update you
thanks

Comment: hi Kris Roofe, can please take a look at the comments under @damianfabian answer

Answer (score 1):

The faster way is use all the resources from China Servers or from your local server. China block all resources from Google, Facebook, etc. So, I recommend you to download all your resources like CSS, Javascript, etc. Or use China servers that already have bootstrap, jQuery and all the libraries that you will need. If you are using google analytics you has to validate before to load this script if the user could load that script, if not then don't load the script because It will stop your page for some seconds until throw an error.

Comment: Does GFC also block script tags and styles tags present in PHP/ Server generated?

Comment: It does not matter where the script is generated at the end the script import a resource from the source, if the source is from a Google server, Facebook or any server block by GFC, It wont charge and will stop your page. i.e

    <script source='http://google.com/scripts/angular-latest.js' />

that script wont be loaded in china because the Firewall

   <script source='http://yoursite.com/js/angular-latest.js' /> 
this script will be loaded because it's from your server

Comment: thanks @damianfabian, i have an assumption regarding the GFC, as per the above comment
"The GFC only blocks access to client (Webbrowsers/ mobile browsers etc), not blocks to server
my server (which is in china) can access the google"
Is this correct?

Comment: noop,if your address is blocked, it block everything. you can try to ping your address to see is caused by your address or some of your scripts

Comment: ok, you have to read about client-server model. Because everything from your server It's allowed but if your webpage have a link to any source blocked, then you webpage won't load that resource what will end with your page don't loading images, css styles or the page at all.

Answer (score 0):

**How we'll give credible and/or official sources without traceroute or domain, IP?** It can be IP blocking, DNS filtering, packet filtering. We are really limited for the sake of security! We can point you towards troubleshooting. You can always use VPN service in China. That is one way.

**We can not say that unable to open site from China means because great firewall of China**. It can be other technical problem. That thing I am pointing to solve.

I am taking that you are from China or has business need in China, and you are using any dedicated host. First check your servers/domains from different ISPs in China. If fails, then run traceroute and ask your host. They will allocate IP which can be assessed from China. That means you are allowed. Simple.

Second is DNS. All standard paid DNS like Dyn will have no problem.

In general, colocation/dedicated with all RFC standards properly maintained, server security is higher, HTTPS Everywhere listed, there is DANE, good cipher suite etc they will not be blocked by China unless they target & block your domain.

Now if for 200 requests of resources on your web page, if 100 are blocked at China, website unlikely to open but you can SSH. What you can do? Make all resources like CSS, Javascript, etc from CDN with own CNAME or inline them. Block of few resources will not matter. It will open.

Here is list of really blocked -- [Websites_blocked_in_mainland_China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websites_blocked_in_mainland_China).

Real block is very difficult to circumvent. It can be IP blocking, DNS filtering, packet filtering. Not exactly easy to say without traceroute. That really we can say very little because it is towards off topic, broad.